# use jQuery .one() function in combination with validation

Tags: jquery

I am working on a forgot Username function that is in a modal using twitter bootstrap.  When the Submit button is clicked I need to run through some validation and if the validation passes make sure the rest of the script is only executed once.

I'm familiar with the `.one()` function and have attempted to use `$(this).one('click', function()` within the `if(isValid)` section with no luck. I've also added `.addClass("disabled");` after the validation check with no luck.

Here is a simplified version of the javascript block:

```
$('#btnForgotUsername').live('click', function (e) {

    // Clear the error div of any previous errors    
    $('#vsForgotUsername').hide().empty();

    var isValid = true;

    // Must Enter Email Address
    var emailEntered = $('#txtEmailAddress').val();
    if (!$.trim(emailEntered).length) {
        $('#vsForgotUsername').append('Email address required');
        isValid = false;
    }
    else {
        // If Email Entered verify that it is a valid email address
        if (!validateEmail(emailEntered)) {
            $('#vsForgotUsername').append('Enter valid email address.');
            isValid = false;
        }
    }

    if (isValid) {
        $('#btnForgotUsername').addClass("disabled");

        var proxy = new serviceProxy('/Login.aspx/', { async: true });
        proxy.invoke
        (
            'forgotUser',
            {
                emailAddress: $('#txtEmailAddress').val()
            },
            function (result) {
                if (result.d == true) {
                    $('#pnlForgotUsername, #btnForgotUsername').hide();
                    $('#pnlForgotUsernameSuccess').fadeIn();
                    return;
                }
                else {
                    $('#btnForgotUsername').removeClass("disabled");
                    $('#vsForgotUsername').fadeIn().append("We do not have a record with that email address.");
                }
            },
            function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            },
            null
        );
    }
    else {
        $('#vsForgotUsername').fadeIn();
    }
});
```

Can someone help me find an approach that will accomplish the validation and only execute the ajax once if validation = true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm. To be honest, I am not entirely clear on what you need but try explicitly setting the prop of the button (I am assuming it is a button).

```
       $('#btnForgotUsername').prop('disabled', true);
```

in Addition I would add a .data to the success and then just test against that ie.

```
$("body").data("ajaxSuccess", "true");
```

Comment: .prop('disabled', true); is all I needed